# Angularjs 1.2.x app not working in IE8/IE7

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

Seems like my Angularjs app doesn't fire up in IE browsers (the ng-view is just left blank).The site is located here: https://ext.makenewsmail.com/subscriptionform/#/1398/4878 and works in all other browsers.

I've done all the recommendations (view sourcecode). Manual boostrap doesn't solve the issue.

Quick recap:
ngRoute with just one route (/:listid/:userid), one template and one controller (mainCtrl).

Any ideas? This is going live tomorrow! I need all the help I can get on this one.

Comment: Have you looked at console output of the browser. FYI it also doesn't load in my Firefox and there are a bunch of url errors in the console log. Please double check.

Comment: My Chrome console doesn't give any errors. It works in FF 26 and again no errors in console. I use Browerstack for viewing IE8 and no script errors there either...I'm will try to run some older version of FF

Comment: It runs in FF 12. What kind of error messages do you get?

Comment: Ops..correct url is https://ext.makenewsmail.com/subscriptionform/#!/1398/4878

Comment: The error message was that url misses a bang. Second link you posted works. Angular documentation says that angularjs is not tested against IE7, it is only tested for IE8 and above. Second link doesn't work in IE11 though. So maybe you are still missing something...

Comment: I'm getting good results in IE10 & 11. There must be some guide for common IE9 pitfalls, i'm sure I hit one of them

Comment: Can't anyone help me out?

Comment: I have been struggling with `ng-view` in the past two days. Same problem. The `createElement` does not help much. Then I discarded `ng-view` altogether and use `ui-router` instead. Finally made it work.

Comment: And shouldn't your base url be `/subscriptionform`?